# Consider every possible pair, remove NaN entries and obtain the linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, loops, linear-regression

I'm working with Python for the first time so I've few difficulties.

I've a csv file of data with 6 columns and 20 rows, some entries are 'NaN'. What I'm trying to do is an interaction that would consider the first column vs the others (A vs B,C,D,E and F), then the second column with all the others (B vs C,D,E and F) etc (i.e compare every possible pair of the 6 columns), for each pair remove the NaN entries (so the number of rows for each final pair would be different) and calculate the linear regression.

I can obtain the results I'm looking for by considering each pair "manually", but since I've quite a lot of DataFrames for which I've to do this procedure, it'd take a lot of time, so I'm hoping someone would help me with a faster method.

Part of my data:

```
| A      | B      | C       | D    | E             | F            |

| 70.385 | 1316.0 | NaN     | 1.84 | 1.021059e+37  | 1.284026e+41 |

| 13.183 | 800.0  | 11549.0 | 1.66 | 4.710032e+35  | Nan          |

| 9.750  | NaN    | NaN     | 1.55 |  1.437108e+36 | 5.070657e+40 |

| 12.302 | NaN    | 547.7   | 1.56 | 2.149507e+36  | 2.294859e+40 |

| NaN    | 2784.2 | 29984.4 | 1.87 | NaN           | 2.294859e+40 |
```

what I'm able to do is:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress

df=data1.dropna(subset=['A','B']) 
lr_AB=linregress(df['A'],df['B'])
```

and what I'm trying to obtain is: LinregressResult(slope= , intercept=, rvalue=, pvalue=, stderr=) for each pair. So, how do I iterate these two commands for every possible pair of columns?

My attempt was this, but without much results:

```
for i in range(len(data1.columns)-1):
    if data1.iloc[:, :] is 'NaN':
        df= data1.dropna()
        print(df)
        lr= linregress(df.iloc[:, i], df.iloc[:, i+1])
    else:
        print('no nan') 
        lr1= linregress(data1.iloc[:, i], data1.iloc[:, i+1])
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small input example data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: @PierreD Hope my edits will be good enough

Comment: Good work, thx. You can go a step further by making your data easier to copy/paste (so we can more easily start helping you). Also, you haven't defined `linregress` exactly, and it would help if you showed what the expected result is (and in what form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'd like to use `scipy.stats`'s `linregress`, here is a way to do this. Not much more efficient than your code, as it also loops over the combinations of columns:

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress
from itertools import combinations

for a, b in combinations(df, 2):
    ab = df[[a, b]].dropna()
    lr[(a, b)] = dict(zip(
        'slope intercept r_value p_value std_err'.split(),
        linregress(ab[a], ab[b])
    ))
    lr[(a, b)]['n_points'] = ab.shape[0]

result = pd.DataFrame(lr).T
```

Sample run on your example data -

```py
>>> result
            slope     intercept   r_value   p_value       std_err  n_points
A B  9.020664e+00  6.810806e+02  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
  C  1.248729e+04 -1.530709e+05  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
  D  4.316155e-03  1.538532e+00  0.942012  0.057988  1.087230e-03       4.0
  E  1.503028e+35 -4.016931e+35  0.984424  0.015576  1.898085e+34       4.0
B C  9.291100e+00  4.116120e+03  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
  D  8.706011e-05  1.647796e+00  0.789115  0.421079  6.776741e-05       3.0
  E  1.887517e+34 -1.462913e+37  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
C D  1.061987e-05  1.547701e+00  0.998360  0.036468  6.090086e-07       3.0
  E -1.525732e+32  2.233071e+36 -1.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
D E  2.896150e+37 -4.429182e+37  0.869114  0.130886  1.165450e+37       4.0
A F  1.525539e+39  2.034718e+40  0.957112  0.187122  4.617784e+38       3.0
B F -7.182537e+37  2.229248e+41 -1.000000  0.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
C F  0.000000e+00  2.294859e+40  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000e+00       2.0
D F  1.097658e+41 -1.308991e+41  0.382452  0.617548  1.875151e+41       4.0
E F  1.061306e+04  1.854240e+40  0.946081  0.210009  3.633822e+03       3.0
```